# Ruby On Rails Jumbotron Background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set the jumbotron background to an image that the user uploaded with paperclip in my Ruby on Rails view.

The problem is that setting the background uses CSS like this:

```
.jumbotron
{
    background-image: url("desired_url")
}
```

whereas I want to put the image that the user uploaded.

The image tag for paperclip is:

```
<image_tag @page.img.url>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to this problem is to think beyond stylesheets for styling. Instead, set the background image with an inline style:

`<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(<%= @page.img.url %>)">`

Comment: Updated with the specific url. Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

as pydsigner said I set the background image within inline style

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(<%= @b.img.url%>)">
```